# How to use Drupal CKEditor Module for nested numbering

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor Module in Drupal, but not able to put nested numbering.
I want to put content like below:

```
1. Text1

   1.1 Text2

       1.1.1 Text3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that functionality is not built into CKEditor. You could use CSS to accomplish the nested numbering. Below is the CSS code used to accomplish this task taken from the Drupal Module page for CKEditor.

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
li {
    display: block;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```